# Babel 7 with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am trying to upgrade my Vue.js project that uses Node.js server (with websocket, etc.) from using Babel 6 to Babel 7. I have downloaded the following NPM packages:

```
- @babel/node
- @babel/preset-env
- @babel/core
- @babel/cli
```

And here is my current `npm script`: `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --presets @babel/preset-env`

Yet. When I run that, I get:

```
➜  ~/vueproj/game git:(feat/items-overhaul) ✗ ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --presets @babel/preset-env
[nodemon] 1.18.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node server.js --presets @babel/preset-env`
/Users/dan/vueproj/game/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/interopRequireDefault.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export default function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I could not find out how to use the CLI as the documentation for that was not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install and run [`@babel/node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) instead.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/node
```

`babel-node` runs `babel` < v7 (calling preset/plugins like `babel-preset-env`) while `@babel/node` will call corresponding babel 7 presets/plugins like `@babel/preset-env`.

and then:

`./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js`

make sure you have a `.babelrc` which calls babel 7 plugins/presets:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

if you run `npx nodemon --help` it doesn't mention a `--presets` option:

```
  --config file ............ alternate nodemon.json config file to use
  -e, --ext ................ extensions to look for, ie. js,jade,hbs.
  -x, --exec app ........... execute script with "app", ie. -x "python -v".
  -w, --watch path.......... watch directory "path" or files. use once for
                             each directory or file to watch.
  -i, --ignore ............. ignore specific files or directories.
  -V, --verbose ............ show detail on what is causing restarts.
  -- <your args> ........... to tell nodemon stop slurping arguments.
```

Comment: Thanks, that I do know. What I was getting is about the newly-updated part. Check out post again -- thank you.

Comment: could you try `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js` with a `.babelrc` in your root project directory

Comment: if you read carefully you will see that @babel/node is not for production... "Not meant for production use" https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node, so seems that the only way to use node and babel is this example https://github.com/babel/example-node-server